# Flagging Overlapping values in two columns

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following data snapshots :

```
ID  NUM1    NUM2
1   1000    1001
2   1002    1003
3   1001    1004
4   1003    1006
5   1007    1008
```

I want to flag the rows which have values occuring both in NUM1 and NUM2 columns:

My desired output would be :

```
ID  NUM1    NUM2    Flag
1   1000    1001    Y
2   1002    1003    Y
3   1001    1004    Y
4   1003    1006    Y
5   1007    1008
```

Can you please help me out here. Thanks

Comment: the rows are flagged because NUM2 has 1001 which occurs in NUM1 in row  3 , and 1003 occurs in NUM2 row 2 and also in NUM1 row 4, that is why they are flagged

Comment: So you want Y if at least one of NUM1 and NUM2 exist somewhere in the other column?

Comment: Is the combination of `(NUM1,NUM2)` unique? How big is your data set?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT id,num1,num2,exists
(
SELECT 1
FROM yourtable 
WHERE num1 IN (SELECT num2 from yourtable)
OR num2 IN (SELECT num1 from yourtable)
) as flag
FROM yourtable
```

output should look like this:

```
ID  NUM1    NUM2    Flag
1   1000    1001    TRUE
2   1002    1003    TRUE
3   1001    1004    TRUE
4   1003    1006    TRUE
5   1007    1008    FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do an `EXISTS` in the select list, to verify if at least one of NUM1 and NUM2 exist somewhere in the table's other column:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.num1, t1.num2,
       exists (select 1 from tablename t2
               where t2.num2 = t1.num1
                  or t2.num1 = t1.num2) as Flag

FROM tablename t1
```

Alternatively, a self `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select distinct t1.*, case when t2.id is not null then 'Y' else 'F' end as flag
from tablename t1
left join tablename t2 on t2.num2 = t1.num1 or t2.num1 = t1.num2
```

Doing `select distinct` to avoid duplicates!